WooCommerce WP_Query to search title and SKU
I am using the following args to search WooCommerce products in the title or the SKU.
The search should do a partial match on the search term e.g.'timb' would match 'Timber chair' in the title or 'M-TIMB' in the SKU.
I am trying the below but it seems to search for products that have the search term in both the title and SKU
What is the correct $args to search for a partial match in the SKU or title?
// Query products matching the search string in their SKU or title
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'product',          // Search in 'product' post type
    'post_status'    => 'publish',          // Only published products
    'posts_per_page' => 20,                 // Limit results to 20 per page
    's'              => $search,            // Search term in title and content
    'meta_query'     => [
        'relation' => 'OR',                 // Either SKU or title
        [
            'key'     => '_sku',
            'value'   => $search,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'               // Partial match on SKU
        ]
    ],
    'fields'         => 'ids'               // Only get post IDs to optimize performance
];

Note this searches the title correctly:
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    's'              => $search, // Search term
    'posts_per_page' => 20,      // Adjust if you need to limit results
];

And this searches the SKU correctly:
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'product',          // Search in 'product' post type
    'post_status'    => 'publish',          // Only published products
    'posts_per_page' => 20,                 // Limit results to 20 per page
    'meta_query'     => [                   // Custom fields query (e.g., SKU)
        [
            'key'     => '_sku',
            'value'   => $search,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'               // Partial match on SKU
        ]
    ],
    'fields'         => 'ids'               
];

If I combine the two as separate calls I get the answer I want but I want to do it with one call.

Based on the comment below I have modified args to:
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'product',          
    'post_status'    => 'publish',          
    'posts_per_page' => 20,                 

    'title_filter' => $search,          // new
    'title_filter_relation' => 'OR',    // new

    'meta_query'     => [
        'relation' => 'OR',          
        [
            'key'     => '_sku',
            'value'   => $search,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'             
        ]
    ],
    'fields'         => 'ids'             
];

but it still returns and AND match

title is also one of the possible arguments, but it looks for exact matches only. Maybe try first, if that gives the expected result, when you look for an exact match - if it does, use a hook to modify the query and insert a LIKE operator, something like https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/18703

I have added a new $args to the question above using the title match. 'title_filter' => $search, 'title_filter_relation' => 'OR'. It doesn't make a difference :-(

You need to also add the functionality that modifies the SQL statement accordingly ...
